# Flutter собрать значения TextField в Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: listview, flutter

Нужно отправить post запрос для этого нужно значения всех TextFiel собрать в  Map что нужно делать TextEditingController
это тестовые данные body, я так понимаю что при изменении поля нужно добавлять значение в map. Как это сделать лучше подскажите.

```
class CreateOrderWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  CreateOrderWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CreateOrderWidgetState createState() => _CreateOrderWidgetState(); 
  }


class _CreateOrderWidgetState extends State<CreateOrderWidget> {

    final formatdate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    final formattime = DateFormat("HH:mm"); 


    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'title':'Hello','adress':'Hello','task':'Hello','times':'Hello','dates':'Hello','city':'Hello','views':    'Hello','status':'Hello','worker':'Hello','name':'Hello','phone': 'Hello','price': 'Hello','stavka':'Hello','userid': 'Hello'};
    // dataform = '{"title":"Hello","adress":"Hello","task":"Hello","times":"Hello","dates":"Hello","city":"Hello","views": "Hello","status":"Hello","worker":"Hello","name":"Hello","phone": "Hello","price": "Hello","stavka":"Hello","userid": "Hello"}';
    void  postApi() async {
    var   catJson = await CatAPI().addOrderApi(body);
    setState(() {
      print(catJson);  
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    postApi();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        ),
        child: Container(

        child: SingleChildScrollView(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36.0),

      child: Column(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[

        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Row(
        children:<Widget>[
          Text("Создание заказа" ,style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 23,
              ),),]),

          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            maxLength: 10,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Название задачи',
                prefixText: '',
                suffixText: '',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            maxLines: 1,
          ),

          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          TextFormField(
             maxLength: 200,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Опишите задачу подробно',
              helperText: 'Максимум 200 символов.',
              labelText: 'Подробное описание задачи',
            ),
            maxLines: 3,
          ),

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              DateTimeField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
              labelText: 'Укажите дату выполнения работ',
              prefixText: '',
              suffixText: '',
              suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
              format: formatdate,           
              onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
              return showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              firstDate: DateTime(1900),
              initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
              lastDate: DateTime(2100));
              },),

 //////////////////////////////////  
             SizedBox(height: 18.0),           
             DateTimeField(
             format: formattime,
             decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
              labelText: 'Укажите время выполнения работ',
              prefixText: '',
              suffixText: '',
              suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
             onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
             final time = await showTimePicker(
              context: context,
            initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
             );
            return DateTimeField.convert(time);
             },
             ),
//////////////////////////////////////////////////     
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          TextFormField( 
              maxLength: 2,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              labelText: 'Сколько нужно человек?',
              prefixText: '',
              suffixText: '',
              suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),

          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          TextFormField(
            maxLength: 6,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.payment),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Укажите оплату на человека в час',
                prefixText: '',
                suffixText: 'Руб',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                maxLines: 1,
          ),


          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          TextFormField(
            maxLength: 30,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Адрес',
                prefixText: '',
                suffixText: '',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                maxLines: 1,
          ),

          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
           RaisedButton(
           color: Colors.blue,
           child: Text("Отправить",style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),),
           onPressed: (){postApi();},
           ),
        ],
      ),

         ),
        ),
      ),
       );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой пример который поможет вам разобраться как получить данные из `TextField` и использовать их (его можно протестировать в [DartPad'е](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/), а также статья по [TextField и Controller](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  Map<String, dynamic> body = Map<String, dynamic>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: myController,
        ),
      ),
      // Кнопка добавления данных из TextField в Map
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.publish),
        onPressed: () => {
          body['title'] = myController.text,
        },
      ),
      // Кнопка для получения данных из Map
      bottomNavigationBar: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.get_app),
        onPressed: () => {body.forEach((k, v) => print(k + ": " + v))},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

А что по поводу вашего `Map`, я предполагаю что это данные для отправки по `API` (в формате `Json`). И если он сложный (где есть множество полей) как у вас: то лучше облегчить себе задачу и использовать сериализацию `Json` с помощью автогенератора кода, чтобы работать через модель, а не с `Map` напрямую. Вот как это сделать: [Automatic Json Serializing](https://medium.com/flutter-community/generate-the-code-to-parse-your-json-in-flutter-c68aa89a81d9), [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) (в обоих случаях используют библиотеку [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), обратите внимание на зависимости!).

---

*И не забывайте про главное правило в программирование: если логика повторяется многократно, то её необходимо вынести в отдельный метод.*

Comment: Спасибо думаю , что данные не меняются а у меня Map статикой заполнен посмотрел ваш код и пришло озарение Map<String, dynamic> body = Map<String, dynamic>();   ))) у меня у сделано через json_serializable,  получение данных я просто не могу понять как он мне помогает при отправке данных , и post запрос не отправляет на сервер json только с Map вышло. у меня там поля form field.

Comment: Спасибо за DartPad не видел раньше

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь!

Comment: у меня генерируется order.g.dart для заказов пока еще не разобрался до конца с этим инструментом , просто столько всего сразу , не знаешь куда двигать)) решил пока самое главное , наладит отправку и получение данных